# Emojis displaying as outline in Chrome, how to fix

Tags: html, css, emoji

I've duplicated a Google my business review box in css for performance, but the emojis inside display as black outlines.  Presumably some style in the parent div is causing this?

Working on that assumption I've tried applying the css style all: unset; and all: intial; 
This has not worked.

The default font for the pages in Roboto, I thought perhaps Roboto displayed emojis weirdly so I tried styling all the emojis as variously Font-family: Sans-serif, then as monospace.  They still didn't display correctly.

[image]

This is afflicting multiple pages on my site, so I'd love some advice.  I need emojis to display correctly.

It displays correctly in Edge and Firefox, so I'm wondering if there is no solution but Google upgrading Chrome.  This would not be good news!

Look for the double ASTERIXS ** below, for the styled EMOJIS, variously ⭐ &

```html
<div style="display:flex; border: 2px solid lightgray; background: white; border-radius: 10px; padding: 16px; line-height: 1.6em; font-size: 1em;">
    <div width="70px" height="70px">
    <div style="border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #C21C5E;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-size: 28px; color: white; font-weight: 400;">
  A</div></div>

<div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 16px; float: right;  letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 0.95em;">
  <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: ">Angela Bowen</div>
  <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 0.95em; line-height: 0.95em; color: gray">10 reviews</div>

  **<div style="color: unset; width: 100%; margin-top: 1.2em; font-size: 0.8em; letter-spacing: 3px;">⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐</div>**
    This is my second Harry Potter tour in Edinburgh and... 
**<span style="color: unset; background-color: unset; border: unset; background: unset;"></span>**
  </div>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: EMOJIS are displaying at my end.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot showing how the emoji display for you?

Comment: Works for me too I see ⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐  and 

Comment: Try adding `border: none !important` in your `span`'s inline styling.

Comment: Thanks Halden, just tried that, hasn't worked.  I'm using Chrome, in other browsers it works, in Chrome it gives empty white shapes with outlines only

Comment: In my personal experience, that just seems to be Chrome's unique style of emojis. I have only seen the outlined versions. All colored emojis I came across so far were always supplied by the site itself, they are not UTF-8 emojis.

Comment: Chrome does display full colour emojis, it boggles me what triggers it to show just outlines.  The more divs, the EMOJI is nested inside the less willing it seems to be to display.  I think it's some inherited style that triggers the EMOJI to outline, but I've no idea what.